# ASP.NET Session Keys expire after PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am new to ASP.NET sessions, and am noticing that the session key/variables stored in the Session are expiring after PostBack.

In the code below, during the first page load, I save some XML to a Session key. Then, if a user clicks on a radio button on the web page, it causes a PostBack. After the PostBack, my Session variable that I stored with the XML data is now NULL.

I thought it may have something to do with the Session.Timeout = 60, but I noticed that even if the user clicks the radio button within the first 10 seconds of first page load, the Session variable is still NULL.

In the doStuff() below, xmlDoc is NULL.

```
public partial class InstallmentBillingPortal : System.Web.Ui.Page
{
    XmlDocument xmlDoc
    {
        get
        {
            return Session["xmlDocKey_3069"] == null ? null : (XmlDocument)Session["xmlDocKey_3069"];
        }
        set
        {
            Session["xmlDocKey_3069"] = value;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Timeout = 60;

        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            var xml = File.ReadALlText(Server.MapPath(@"request.xml"));
            xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);
        }
        else
        {
            doStuff();
        }
    }

    void doStuff()
    {
        if (xmlDoc != null)
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Data stored inside **SessionState** available til user closes the browser or session timeout. Therefore, you  want to check `xmlDoc == null` instead of `IsPostBack`.

Do not set SessionState timeout inside a page. Instead, you want to set it inside ***web.config***. For example, 60 minutes -

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>         
     <sessionState timeout="60"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>

XmlDocument xmlDoc
{
    get { return (XmlDocument) Session["xmlDocKey_3069"]; }
    set { Session["xmlDocKey_3069"] = value; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (xmlDoc == null)
    {
        var xml = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(@"request.xml"));
        xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);
    }

    doStuff();
}
```

**FYI:** If you just want data to live during postbacks, you might want to consider using ***View State***.

Comment: I have to check IsPostBack, because a lot of things depend on whether it's the first time the page loads. If it's the first time the page loads, we actually make a WebService call to fetch XML data. Using the received XML data, we populate many grids, radio buttons, text fields, and other controls. On PostBack, we process user inputs, and respond to any triggered events. So I have to use IsPostBack to make those determinations. If the data stored inside SessionState should be available until user closes the browser or session timeout, then why is my SessionState gone on PostBack?

Comment: Also, I noticed our Web.config file already had a SessionState timeout set to 10. Which is still much longer than needed. Even after 5 seconds after first Page Load, my variable in the SessionState is gone. However, I do see two other keys in there. So I don't think the entire SessionState is gone. Maybe just my variable?

Comment: If Session.Abandon is called, is the ViewState lost as well?

Answer (score 0):

asp.net provides the file name global.asax where you can maintain values of the such types of sessions.Try using the files because its scope till main session of page expires.And you would able to keep wath on time of sessions